# Android Studio freezes on open Big Sur

Tags: android, android-studio, macos-big-sur

So I've been using Android Studio 4.2 on my mac with no issue for quite some time, however today while in the middle of working on an app it froze for about 20 minutes until eventually I force quit it. Everytime i try reopening it it is immediatley frozen and shows this error:

[image]

My activity monitor also reports that it is using 950% of my CPU (I only have 6 cores). I have tried increasing the memory of Xmx like it says quite high, my system has 32gb of DDR4 so it should be fine but no change i make seems to actually do anything and the application just remains frozen.

Anyone have a similar issue or ideas of how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

**Introduction:**

This is the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/studio-config.html) that contains more specific details.
In your case use **WAY1** of 2 ways to get to the configuration file.

---

**WAY 1 - Reaching file through Directory + Documentation:**

**macOS**

Syntax: `~/Library/Application Support/Google/<product><version>`

Example: `~/Library/Application Support/Google/AndroidStudio4.1`

**Windows**

Syntax: `%APPDATA%\Google\<product><version>`

Example: `C:\Users\YourUserName\AppData\Roaming\Google\AndroidStudio4.1`

**Linux**

Syntax: `~/.config/Google/<product><version>`

Example: `~/.config/Google/AndroidStudio4.1`

---

For Android Studio versions 4.0 and lower, configuration files are located in the following locations:

**Windows:** `%USERPROFILE%\.CONFIGURATION_FOLDER`

**macOS:** `~/Library/Preferences/CONFIGURATION_FOLDER`

**Linux:** `~/.CONFIGURATION_FOLDER`

There should be a `studio64.exe.vmoptions` file, you also can reach through the steps below.

---

**WAY 2 - Reaching file in Android Studio:**

You can create/edit this file by accessing "Edit Custom VM Options" from the "Help" menu at the top section.

---

**General Settings for memory:**

For quick access to increase your "Maximum heap size" I write this steps for better overview:

1. Click **File** > **Settings** from the menu bar (or **Android Studio** > **Preferences** on macOS).
2. Click **Appearance & Behavior** > **System Settings** > **Memory Settings**.

[image: Preferences]

3. Adjust the heap sizes to match your desired amounts.
4. Click **Apply**.

Note: If you changed the heap size for the IDE, you must restart Android Studio before the new memory settings are applied.

---

**After you reached the file studio64.exe.vmoptions:**

Edit it in Android Studio (1. Headline) or right click it and "Edit" with Notepad or Textdocument. Now the `studio64.exe.vmoptions` should contain following line of codes:

```
-Xms128m
-Xmx4096m
-XX:MaxPermSize=1024m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=200m
-XX:+UseCompressedOops
```

`Xmx` specifies the maximum memory allocation pool for a Java Virtual Machine (JVM), while `Xms` specifies the initial memory allocation pool. Your JVM will be started with `Xms` amount of memory and will be able to use a maximum of `Xmx` amount of memory.

Save the `studio64.exe.vmoptions` file and restart Android Studio.

---

**Restart IDE and clear your Cache:**

Since Android Studio is based on IntelliJ, the option should be in the same place. It's a feature you would seldom use unless your file caches went ballistic (and that can happen every now and then).

Under **File** > **Invalidate Caches/Restart**, you'll find an option that lets you either invalidate the caches (and you'll have to rebuild indexes again), or just restart the IDE.

---

**What in this specific case helped:**

@Quinn did a reinstallation because he had no access inside android studio. That fixed the cache issue of course also.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't access my android studio preferences - the application freezes the second its opened so I cant change any settings from withing android studio

Comment: I updated my answer to clarify how to approach what you want. I suggest to use **WAY 2** to get to the folder and add the content I wrote at the very end of my answer. Now you have all information that are needed. Good luck, I tried to explain as exactly as I could. Cheers

Comment: I have updated that file to make Xmx to be 12000, and still get the same popup shown in my question... the popup shows the box with 12000 in it but still says current value 1280, so not sure if the change is actually taking affect

Comment: Actually activity monitor is showing it immediately takes up 12 gb right when i launch it, before it would only take 4 - So it seems it just consumes all the available memory it can and then freezes no matter how much memory i give it

Comment: Then I would clear your memory. And restart your computer and try to launch Android studio again. Probably there is conflict with your memory cache.

Comment: At the very end of my answer I added how to restart and clear your cache. That should work. Good luck with that!

Comment: I know how to invalidate cache but like i mentioned Android Studio freezes right away on open, i have no way to access the file menu to hit that button. Ive tried restarting my computer and ive tried deleting ~/.gradle/caches neither worked

Comment: May just need to try reinstalling android studio which sucks because ive got a bunch of customizations with hotkeys and themes

Comment: I want to solve that problem in general that's why I write also for others facing that issue. You can delete that file: .idea/caches/ to have access to your android studio back again. Also unpluck all physical devices from usb. That can cause that issue also.

Comment: where is the .idea/caches file?

Comment: It's on Mac: ~/.gradle/caches/

Comment: Yeah, in my last comment i had mentioned i already tried deleting that but it didnt help :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234486/discussion-between-dex7ra-and-quinn).